# Is $\{f\in H^1;\;\int f=0\}$ dense in $\{f\in L^2;\;\int f=0\}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $L_*^2=\left\{f\in L^2(a,b);\;\int_a^b f\;dx=0\right\}$ and $H_*^1=\left\{f\in H^1(a,b);\;\int_a^b f\;dx=0\right\}$, where  $-\infty<a<b<\infty$.

Is $H_*^1$ dense in $(L_*^2,\|\cdot\|_{L^2})$?

Thanks.

Comment: I think $\{f\in C^{\infty}[a,b]: \int_a^bf(x)dx=0\}$ is a subspace of both of your sets and is dense in both of them.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Have you any idea how to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is YES.

We know that every $f\in L^2(a,b)$ can be $L^2$-approximated by continuous functions in $[a,b]$. For example, this can be done with Fourier series - If $f\in L^2(a,b)$, then 
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\hat f_{\!\!k}\,\mathrm{e}^{ik\frac{2\pi}{b-a}x},
$$
where $\hat f_{\!\!k}=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{e}^{-ik\frac{2\pi}{b-a}x}\,dx$, and with
$$
\|f\|_{L^2(a,b)}^2=(b-a)\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}|\,\hat f_{\!\!k}|^2.
$$ 
Then for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a sufficiently large $n$, such that
$$
\|f-f_n\|_{L^2(a,b)}<\varepsilon,
$$
where 
$$
f_n(x)=\sum_{|k|\le n}\hat {f_k}\,\mathrm{e}^{ik\frac{2\pi}{b-a}x}, \tag{1}
$$ 
and clearly $f_n\in C[a,b]$. In fact $f_n\in C^\infty[a,b]$ and in particular $f_n\in H^1(a,b)$.

If in particular $f\in L_*^2(a,b)$, then $\hat {f_0}=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=0$, and thus $f_n$, as defined by $(1)$ will also have a vanishing $\hat {f_0}$ term, and hence 
$$
\int_a^b f_n(x)\,dx=0,
$$
as well. In fact, this means that $f_n\in H^1_*(a,b)$.

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question. What happens if we replace $L_*^2$ by $L^2$? I think $H_*^1$ is not dense in $L^2$. Can you help me with this case?

Comment: $H_*^1$ is dense in $L^2$. Even better, the $C_0^\infty$ is dense in $L^2$!

Comment: Probably this is a trivial question, but could you explain me how can we see that $H_*^1$ is dense in $L^2$?

Comment: First, take $f\in L^2$, $L^2-$approximate it by a smooth function $g$ and then modify $g$, so that it vanishes at $a$ and $b$, and in the intervals $[a,a+\varepsilon]$, $[b-\varepsilon,b]$ is linear. The last function is in $H_*^1$.

Comment: What are $g(a+\varepsilon)$, $g(b-\varepsilon)$ and $g(x)$ for $x\in(a+\varepsilon, b-\varepsilon)$?

Comment: $g(a+\varepsilon)$ and $g(b-\varepsilon)$ remain unmodified, and starting from there we draw lines to $(a,0)$ and $(b,0)$ respectively.

Comment: Let $G$ be the modified function. Why $\int G = 0$?

Comment: You can define $h(x)=\max\{1-|x|,0\}$. Then $h\ge 0$, $h\in H^1$, and $\int h^2<2/3$. Let $s=\int_a^b g$ and set $G_N(x)=g(x)-sNh(N(x-c))$, where $c=(a+b)/2$. Then $\int G_N=0$, and $\|G_N-g\|\le N^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Yiorgos S. Smyrlis, We have $H_*^1\subset L^2_*$ and thus, if $H_*^1$ is dense in $L^2$, then $L^2_*$ is dense in $L^2$. As $L^2_*$ is closed in $L^2$, $L^2_*$ can not be dense in $L^2$ and thus $H_*^1$ is not dense in $L^2$. What is right: this argument or your comment above?